# How can I check values in a C++ map without getting compiler errors in a "const" member function?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, constants

I have a member function that compares data in a C++ map. I declared the member function as constant:

```
bool operator == (UnitSet otherSet) const;
```

but as soon as I use myMap["l"] to access and compare values I get compiler errors about myMap being constant. Is there a way around this while keeping the const directive?

I know an empty value is created for the "l" key if it didn't exist when I check it, but that won't change the value / behaviour of my UnitSet - maybe I'm trying to be too picky here though and should just drop the "const". What is the good way to go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map` unfortunately doesn't have a `const` overload of the `[]` operator. This is because whenever you access a key that doesn't exist, the map creates an element for it; if the map was `const`, that would be impossible. Therefore, there's no way to call it with a constant map. It isn't related to the behavior of your `UnitSet` class.

You'll have to use `myMap.find(TKey)` to get an iterator to your element, which returns `myMap.end()` if it can't find it.

Map iterators point to a `std::pair` of your key and value, so you need to access the `second` member of it to get your value (`first` being the key).

```
const UnitSet& reference = myMap.find("l")->second;
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you should change your function signature to accept otherSet by const reference, as you have no need to copy it and won't be modifying it:

```
bool operator==(const UnitSet& otherSet) const;
```

Then, rather than using the non-`const` `operator[]`, use `find()` or `begin()`/`!=end()`/`++` to get `const_iterator`s into your `map`s for the comparison.  As `find()`, `begin()` and operations on `const_iterator` only require `const` access to `map`, they can be used from your `const` member function.

```
map<X, Y>::const_iterator i = the_map.find(key);
if (i != the_map.end())
    // here, i->first is the key, i->second is the value
else
    // key wasn't in the map after all...
```

Comment: Thanks, good point about the reference as well, I'm new to objects passing by value and such, coming from an obj-c background.